# How to find whether strikeThrough /underline is present in word document using office.js

Tags: office-js, javascript-api-for-office, word-web-addins

I am working on Word web-in using office.js.

I have a requirement like when I load the document on word if user makes any strikeThrough or Underline in the document.Need to retrieve the value whether it is True/False.

As of now I am able to retrieve the value for current selection.But here I need the value on the whole document

Example:-It might be one letter/one word.Basically It should return results by searching in whole document(n no of pages).

```
Word.run(function (context) {
            var range = context.document.body;
            range.load('font');
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Font: " + range.font.strikeThrough);
                    console.log("Size: " + range.font.size);

                });
        });
```

So It always shows value as "false" though word marked as strikeThrough in total document that was loaded on Word.

Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [search method in the Word.Body object](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#search-searchtext--searchoptions-).

Comment: In search we are having many search options.I used normal search and wildcard but still results are 0.Please share sample piece of code